# how to drag object from one view to another view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

Hi I am new to ios development. I am trying to drag label from view to tool bar...but the label is going to back side of the tool bar.i want label drag infront of the toolbar..please any on help me regarding this issue......this is the code i did up to now

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar *backgrdtoolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,44)];

    [backgrdtoolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

    [self.view addSubview:backgrdtoolbar];

    mainScroll =  [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 45)];

    [mainScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600,45)];
    [mainScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [mainScroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

    mainToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 44)];
    [mainToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

    [self.view addSubview:mainScroll];

    [mainScroll addSubview:mainToolbar];

    UIBarButtonItem *b1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"1" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(_1:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *b2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"2" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(_1:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *b3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"3" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(_1:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:b1,spacer,b2,spacer,b3, spacer,b4,spacer,b5,spacer,b6,spacer,b7,spacer,b8,spacer,b9,spacer,b10,nil];
    [mainToolbar setItems:arr];

}



 - (IBAction)handle:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
        static CGRect originalFrame;

        if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
            originalFrame = gesture.view.frame;
        } else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
            CGPoint translate = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view.superview];

            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(fmin(gesture.view.superview.frame.size.width - originalFrame.size.width, fmax(originalFrame.origin.x + translate.x, 0.0)),
                                         fmin(gesture.view.superview.frame.size.height - originalFrame.size.height, fmax(originalFrame.origin.y + translate.y , 0.0)),
                                         originalFrame.size.width,
                                         originalFrame.size.height);


            gesture.view.frame = newFrame;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Where's the label? What is the gesture attached to?

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to drag one view to another view? Yes it is possible.

But if the only thing that matter to you is to put the label in front of the other view, I believe that the best approach is not change the view that your label is in. By that I mean you do not need to change others views, that are inside your destination view.

If I were in your shoes, I will use one view that has the view that your label is placed to contain both views, the View that you place your label and the view that you want that your label can be dragged.

When you add your Label to this view, the important point to observe, is that it must be in front of your views, you can do that using this code:

```
[view bringSubviewToFront:yourLabel];
```

After that you can drag it inside your view container and it will be in front of the others views. :)

-

If you really want to change it from one view to another view, you must remove it from your original view, and add it to the other view that it will be placed. Something like that

```
if(gesture.view.frame.origin.y > y ) {
    [gesture.view removeFromSuperview];
    [newView addSubview:gesture.view];
    //Your code to adjust the frame for the new view, because your frame is relative
    //It is define by your superview
}
```

Comment: I would vote for `[view bringSubviewToFront:yourLabel]` as the better solution than actually moving the label to another view.